# hibernate session clear

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I making application which importing a lot of informations from another application.

My application make a lot of inserts to database, but all inserts are in big loop.

It looks like this:

I get `List<SomeObject> someObject`;

I make loop:

```
    for(Object object : someObject){
       someClass1.insertToDB(object);
       someClass2.insertToDB(object);
       someClass3.insertToDB(object);
       someClass4.insertToDB(object);
    }
```

After last insert i want to clear session.

And my question is, if i will make `session.flush; session.clear;` on `someClass4.insertToDB` does it will clear also elements which were userd in `someClass1, someClass2 and someClass3` ? Does it clear whole session ?

Thianks

Comment: The large number of typos in your question title suggest a level of laziness that makes me not want to read this question any further.

Comment: If you are using the same session object then YES